# Conditionally flag fields for each group (2 columns) based on top N values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I'm trying to get "First Past the Post" figures, and compare this to the Proportional Representation winners for all election counts.  I have all the data in the fields below since 1933, but I can't work out the formula.  I might need to extract more data, but I'm hoping not to go there...

Essentially, for each grouping of "Year" and "Constituency", I want the top N of "FirstCount".  The top N is the count of the Winner column > 0.

In the example below I want to create a new column called "First Past Post" which would be the same as "Winner" for 2016, but for 2020 the first 3 rows would be 1, and all below that would be 0.  The number of "Winners" can be 3,4 or 5 (Count of Winner for Year and Constituency)

```
Year, Constituency, First Count, Winer
2020, Limerick County, 9228, 1
2020, Limerick County, 8436, 1
2020, Limerick County, 6916, 0
2020, Limerick County, 6021, 1
2020, Limerick County, 5810, 1
2016, Limerick County, 12276, 1
2016, Limerick County, 8479, 1
2016, Limerick County, 8013, 1
2016, Limerick County, 5432, 0
```

Comment: 1. "but for 2020 the first 3 rows would be 1,"... is not reflected in the tables shared.. does this means you had tried a formula that produce the current result..?  2. "The number of "Winners" can be 3,4 or 5 "... how should the output look like if the given table is used as the input?

Comment: Thanks for responding when I say "but for 2020 the first 3 rows would be 1,"....I'm referring to the "Winner" column.  for 2020 it is 1,1,0.  However, the output I want would be 1,1,1 which reflects the fact that 9228, 8436 & 6916 are in the top 3

Comment: For "The number of "Winners" can be 3,4 or 5 ", I need the nth top values.  Which is the Sum of "Winner" for "Year" and "Constituency".  In this case it would be 3.....however in 2008, Wcklow say it could be 4 or 1992, Cork it could be 5.  Sorry, if I haven't been clear - does that make more sense?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you are looking for two output values. 1st is the winner (which will be 1 or 0) for each row. and 2nd is the count (of winner's 1) for each year... || If that is the case.. just focus on one year (list down only one year full data), share us the formula/link/ref you read/tried to apply and failed/partially working, for the winner, or the winner count.. It would ease others to assist..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10;A2;$B$2:$B$10;B2;$C$2:$C$10;">"&C2)+1`

Maybe this is helpful. It lists the ranking of matching data in column A and B.
If they don't match it resets the ranking.